# node-pg-migrate doesn't use config.json file

Tags: node-pg-migrate

I'm passing the --config-file flag but it just wont read the thing, do I really need to install a package for something as simple as reading a configuration file? am I doing something wrong?, I run it like so :

```sh
  npm run migrate up --config-file "./myconfig.json"
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to install the npm package `config`.